# Using global variable outiside document ready javascript?

Tags: javascript

Looking trough this site I have seen a number of suggestions about how to update a global variable inside document ready, and then use it outside document ready.  I have tried a number of combinations of these and none of these seem to work.  Any help?  What am I missing?

```
test = 0 ;
```

or

```
var test = 0;
```

or

```
test;
```

or

```
var test;
```

or no declaration outside document ready at all

then

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  test = 4;
});
```

then later...

```
alert(test);
```

output:0, or undefined.  Why oh why don't you output 4 like I want you to!  I know, I wish I could just use a normal function where this works easily, but I can't.  I need to use document ready to get some json/jplot material to work.

Comment: what are you really trying to do? what have you tried? Try explaining using jsfiddle

Comment: is this what you had in mind? http://jsfiddle.net/LRyKN/

Comment: I am trying to take a JSON value from a graphing function inside document ready.  I am then trying to use it in an HTML table outside the document ready function.  But I can't figure out how to get a variable obtained inside document ready, and use it elsewhere.

Comment: @MatthewClarkson How do you use it in a table? Do you have Javascript code inside the table?

Comment: Where is the JSON value coming from? Are you performing an AJAX call first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test = 4;` will create a global variable and set it to 4. It's equivalent to the more explicit `window.test = 4`.

Before the global variable has been created it's value will be returned as undefined.

You need to make sure to call `alert(test)` after the document ready handler has run. That means you either need to call it in an event handler or call a function from inside document ready.

If you just call `alert(test)` below the document ready handler it will be executed immediately when the page is loaded - at that point its value will be `undefined`. Only once the document is ready the `test` is set to 4.

Also note that any local variables called `test` will shadow the global variable, i.e., the value of the local variable will be used instead of that of the global one. You can avoid this by using `window.test`.

---

There are two things you can do:

- Add an id to the fields in the table and then set their content in the document ready handler
- Insert the table once the rest of the page has finished loading and test has been set

I'd recommend the first approach:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  test = 4;
  document.getElementById("test-value").innerHTML = test
});
```

With this html code:

```
<table>
    <!-- ...whatever else you have -->
    <td id="test-value"></td>
    <!-- ... -->
</table>
```

---

If you want to use `<script>document.write(test)</script>` you need to insert the html code of the table by setting innerHTML (see above) to "..." inside the document ready handler.

You can do it like this but it will be more painful than this needs to be. If you just set innerHTML to something like "document.write(test)" the browser will think the script tag containing the document ready handler has been closed.

Instead I would suggest you use a template engine, such as [`_.template` in underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#template). Then you basically put the HTML inside a script tag and only show it when you're in document.ready. At that point you will be able to specify variables that will be replaced inside the template.

Comment: Is there a way to put an HTML inside the document ready function?

Comment: describe what you mean by *put an HTML* please

Comment: @MatthewClarkson Not using `document.write` the way you do at the moment. It will be executed as soon as the page is loaded, but `test` won't be set until the entire page has finished loading.

Comment: Is there a way I can display the HTML table only after the document is ready and the variable has been set?  Like buy delaying it, or calling it from inside document ready?

Comment: Just updated the question with a different approach, but will add something about doing it the way you suggest.